# R Quantmod Package Delisted from Yahoo?

Tags: r, api, quantmod

I noticed this morning that requests for FTSE indexes from Yahoo Finance via the quantmod and rtsdata getSymbols functions are returning NA values for today. Reproducible code:

```
FTSEAll <- as.data.frame(getSymbols("^FTAS", src = 'yahoo', auto.assign = FALSE, 
                                    from = "2020-01-01"))
```

Individual symbols are still up to date but any kind of FTSE index returns NA for the latest (07-04-2020).

I checked the issues and announcements of the GitHub pages but haven't found anything. Is this an error that happens on regular occasions and related to LSE server volatility?

Comment: You are getting a NA value for yesterday. Weirdly enough the stocks in the FTSE are returning all the data. It wouldn't surprise me if tomorrow the data would include the data for the 7th (or even in an hour or 2). Yahoo tends to have issues with summer time and different timezones. See issue [258](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/258) and related issues on github.

Comment: Hello. Yes it usually returns data only for the previous day (the price of free APIs) but normally the values are at least correct. This is why I'm confused as that would imply it's not a volatility issue and if the API were barred from connection, why am I still able to grab historical data?

Comment: The API is not barred from connection, the server just doesn't return any data for yesterday (yet). The issue is not just with ^FTAS, but also for ^AEX and other European indices.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like something is up with the UK indices on yahoo finance. Check yahoo page for the [FTAS](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EFTAS%3FP%3D%5EFTAS/history/) historical data. It's all blank on 7th April 2020. Same thing happens on the [FTSE100](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EFTSE%3FP%3DFTSE/history/). Maybe the data has not been updated yet but this is odd and in my experience I can get the data as soon as the market closes.

We can use `getQuote()` to get the previous close. This is more of a workaround than a solution.

```r
getQuote("^FTAS", what=yahooQF("Previous Close"))[, 2]
[1] 3141.28
```

Which matches the close on Google Finance:

[image]